# C# Tableadapter dataset reference

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, dataset, tableadapter

I have a dataset named: **FileUploadDataSet.xsd**

and i have the following table adapter:

[image]

The start of my default.aspx.cs page looks like this:

[image]

But i get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'FileUploadDataSetTableAdapters' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to bind the dataset with a gridview and then would like to carry out some insert statements also. But i cant seem to get out of first gear. My dataset is saved in the App_Code folder.

Any ideas to get a young C# nOObie going with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be name what you given on using statment not match with the real class name.

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> or  view => class view

find your table adapter class and drag and drop to code area.  then it will give you the full class name with namespace like `DataSet1TableAdapters.t1TableAdapter`

you can move `DataSet1TableAdapters` to using statement and use directly `t1TableAdapter`

there is no issue with having data set on your app code folder.

**Edit:** if you are not see the classes generated from Dataset you may need to recreate it correctly.

Comment: I dont see my dataset in class view.. :S

Comment: ones you create data set and data adapters, build the project classes will auto generate for you.

Comment: i have tried that. the classes do no auto generate... this is really strange?

Comment: i fixed it, i was in class view and then added a class and selected dataset. thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Open Dataset Adapter from Solution Explorer and go to the properties window if doesnot open by right click, go to View menu and open. There are two properties one is namespace and other is name. You have to change the namespace (http://tempuri.org/DatabaseBookingDAL.xsd) to (http://tempuri.org/**Your namespace Name**.xsd) and also change the name properties of your class

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, solved by add this code:

```
using test.App_Data.testDataSetTableAdapters;
```

where:

> 

test : the name of your project

> 

App_Data : folder contain your database

> 

testDataSet : the name of your data set

> 

it's work correctly :)